# Error: Could not find or load main class C:.Program Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:.Program java11, intellij IDEA and javafx 11

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a project using Intellij IDEA, JDK 11 and openjfx 11. everything seems to have been configured properly but when I add the path to the Javafx jar and add the needed javafx modules for my project in the VM options and run the code, I the following error 
`Error: Could not find or load main class C:.Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:.Program`

when I remove the modules and path configuration from the VM options, i get the following error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader` , which  I think it's because I don't have 
 the javafx modules in the vm option which are is required when using javafx11

how do I fix this problem? have i done a wrong configuration? I have combed the internet for the past 24 hours but couldn't get the help I wanted. Looking forward to your help. Thanks

Comment: Please share your VM options, or even better, a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, I highly recommend using Gradle. I created a minimal example for you here: https://github.com/micheljung/javafx-gradle-example

Comment: Try using the javafx-maven-plugin and starting using "mvn javafx:run" (You'll have to specify a main class in the plugin configs). See the following: https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin This is of course presuming that you're using maven, which you might not be, but it's highly recommended